# Photoshop blurring peaks (it's hard to describe in text)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, photoshop-scripting

I want to know how to blur something in peaks, here's a picture to help describe it:

[image]

Segment C is blurred the most then B then A to create an effect like the one on the right but with blur.

I was wondering if there was a way to do this but on a finer scale with more segments that did not involve me selecting 1 pixel tall rows then applying motion blur..

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you could do this:

1. Select all the layers you want to blur and then go <kbd>Cmd+G</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd+E</kbd> ( <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> isn't necessarily needed )
2. Take the Brush tool and Soft round brush ( round brush with 0 hardness ) and make the brush really big ( big enough to cover the whole area you want to blur )
3. Then run it across the area you want to blur while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> button ( If needed, do it multiple times. )

[image]

If you really want the peak to be tight, you can use few different brush sizes.

**OR**

- Select all the layers you want to blur and then go <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> ( <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> isn't necessarily needed )
- Make a new gradient. Gradient that has 3 opacity stops going from 0%
  to 100% and back to 0% Color doesn't matter ( I used red so that it's
  very visible )

[image]

- Make a new layer where you place the gradient. Hide the layer.

[image]

- Click the gradient layers thumbnail while pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> to
  make a selection from it.

[image]

- Then use Gaussian blur filter on it.

[image]

---

---

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in windows.

Comment: If you store the selection as a layer mask or alpha channel, you can reference the mask when using certain filters (such as lens blur IIRC). At least, in PS you can.

Comment: In addition, you can store the unmodified (sharp) selection (Layer Mask) then use the Feature properties in the Mask properties panel to adjust feathering... non-destructively, so you can change it.  Cheers!

Comment: Oh!  I just realized, you can do the same thing in Photoshop CS6 using Filters>Blur>Tilt-Shift..., without having to define a selection at all.  Better yet, if you convert the layer to a Smart Object (Smart Filter) you can apply the Tilt-Shift blur non-destructively.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Feather your selections before applying the blur filter.